# How to show autocompletion for empty Gtk+ Entry

Tags: python, input, autocomplete, gtk, gtk3

How can i use Gtk+ 3 [EntryCompletion](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/EntryCompletion.html) and [Entry](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Entry.html) to show auto completion suggestions even if the entry is empty?

I tried forcing the entry to show the auto completion with `completion.complete()` but it does not work.

My code looks something like this:

`class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def init(self):
        Gtk.Window.init(self, title="...")
        # ...
        self.liststore = Gtk.ListStore(str)
        self.completion = Gtk.EntryCompletion()
        self.completion.set_model(self.liststore)
        self.completion.set_text_column(0)
        #...
        for h in history:
            self.liststore.append((h,))
        #...
        self.query_entry = Gtk.Entry()
        self.query_entry.set_completion(self.completion)
        self.completion.complete()`

Another thing i would like to know: If i want to auto-complete file paths, how can i force showing the auto completion suggestions right after i selected an auto completion?

Comment: One question per post, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the completion to popup using:

```
self.completion.set_minimum_key_length(0)
self.query_entry.emit('changed')
```

This sets the completion to show the completion even with no text, and the `emit('changed')` is what happens when the text changes.